# ios logical comparison of views

Tags: ios

```
- (int)indexOfView:(id)view {
    for(int i = 0; i < self.subviews.count; ++i) {
        UIView *v = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if(v == view) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This always returns -1. I suspect the problem is with `v == view`. Is that incorrect?

Comment: It looks okay. I'd guess `view` really isn't a subview of `self`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it always returns -1, then it's not in there.

But you should throw away a few lines of code:

```
[self.subviews indexOfObject:view]
```

[NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and its methods are your friend.  The `indexOfObject:` method will return `NSNotFound` in stead of -1.

If it's a subclass of one of the contained views, then it won't show up.  Particularly if you're dealing with an `NSTableViewCell`.

Comment: well that was quite the oversight on my part.. anyway, now I'm always gettging `2147483647` via `NSLog(@"%i", [self.superview.subviews indexOfObject:self]);` any ideas?

Comment: likely == NSNotFound, need more details: classes in use, time to get into the debugger and see what's going on